# Django - is it possible to show full inline form?

Tags: django

I have inline form setup for many-to-many field

```
class DaysInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Reservation.reserved_days.through

class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (DaysInline,)
    exclude = ('reserved_days',)
```

it looks like this

[image]

if i click on edit, form appears in new window

[image]

Is it possible to show full form on each line instead of select ? So i can see edit form for each entry directly on page, without clicks

Comment: try with `admin.StackedInline`

Comment: Well, now you've changed to using the through model, that *is* the full form; the through model is just foreign keys to days, so that is all you can change. If you want to actually create and edit days, then you need to use the Day model. As I said originally, I really think that your models are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [admin.StackedInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline) instead of `TabularInline`

```
admin.StackedInline
```

Comment: You can add fields by `fields` attribute in inline class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

Comment: for inline that doesnt work. I get exception with about unknown fields